# update: no error, if entry doesnt exist

Tags: php, sql

I'm just wondering: if an entry doesn't exist, "UPDATE" also makes an "update"?
I use following code and the if-statement always has "success", especially when the email can't be found by "WHERE". Do I have to check, if the email exists in the table?

```
$email=...;
if ($update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET password = ?, salt = ? WHERE email='".$email."'"))
         {
         $update_stmt->bind_param('ss', $password, $random_salt);

         $update_stmt->execute()
         header("Location: ...?success=1");
         }
         else
            header("Location: ...?error=1");
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: if the entry does not exist, what record will be updated?

Comment: If the `WHERE` clause doesn't match any rows, nothing is performed. You can check the [affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Comment: In SQL, the semantics of errors is not what you are using them for. It is perfectly fine to make a request that does not return any rows. Why should it be an error? Errors relate, mostly but not exclusively, to syntax errors or errors executing certain operations. If you need to produce an error when no update is performed, you have to check if any rows were returned and produce an error if there were none.

Comment: Thats right, Eric. I had to check the affected rows. The SQL-syntax was ok.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you redirect **either if the match exists or not**

```
$update_stmt->execute()
if($update_stmt->affected_rows != 0)
{
    header("Location: ...?success=1");
}
else
{   
    header("Location: ...?error=1");
}
```

also remove that `if` before your query, so final code will look like

```
$update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET password = ?, salt = ? WHERE email='".$email."'"))
$update_stmt->bind_param('ss', $password, $random_salt);
$update_stmt->execute()
if($update_stmt->affected_rows != 0)
{
    header("Location: ...?success=1");
}
else
{   
    header("Location: ...?error=1");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fabio. Your code saved my day. to if-check the "$mysqli->prepare(...)" is also not necessary, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the number of rows that were affected by the previous operation. This is provided by [`affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

```
if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 1)
{
   echo 'A record was deleted';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email=...;
$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET password = ?, salt = ? WHERE email='".$email."'"))
$update_stmt->bind_param('ss', $password, $random_salt);
$update_stmt->execute();

if ($update_stmt->affected_rows > 0){
   header("Location: ...?success=1");
         }
else
   header("Location: ...?error=1");
```

Comment: query will be always executed, you need to check if an update has been done